# Вызов деструктора объекта при исключении в конструкторе, для полей

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть ли в стандарте гарантии, или же какая-нибудь информация о том что будет с сконструированными полями класса, при исключении в конструкторе?

Что мне нужно от этого? Это вызов деструктора у объекта, который является полем класса:

```
namespace ori {
    namespace platform {
        namespace windows {
            struct window
                : public ::ori::gui::window {
            public:
                window(::ori::types::string const &);
                window(::ori::types::string const &, ::ori::u32, ::ori::u32);

            private:
                ::ori::obj m_field; /* Для этого объекта нужен вызов деструктора */

...
            };
        } // namespace windows
    } // namespace platform
} // namespace ori
```

Comment: да, это одна с базовых гарантий. Если в конструторе происходит исключение, то для всех уже созданных переменных класса будут вызваны их деструкторы.

Comment: Хорошо, а можно ответ оформить, и желательно ссылку на параграф в сандарте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То, что описано в вопросе - один с основополагающих принципов с++ и называется он RAII, точнее - одно с его проявлений.

Собственно стандарт дает много гарантий на эту тему https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw

> If an exception is thrown from a constructor or (rare) from a destructor of an object (regardless of the object's storage duration), destructors are called for all fully-constructed non-static non-variant (until C++14)members and base classes, in reverse order of completion of their constructors.

Собственно, что и просили. Правда тут есть особый случай - делегированные конструкторы.

Теперь к ссылке на стандарт. В с++11 в документе n3337, пункт 15.2 Constructors and destructors

> 2 An object of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction is terminated by an exception will
> have destructors executed for all of its fully constructed subobjects (excluding the variant members of a
> union-like class), that is, for subobjects for which the principal constructor (12.6.2) has completed execution
> and the destructor has not yet begun execution.